# angularjs directive testcase in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZPedqHkwjCgmLWw6594e?p=preview
There was some error when running the code on plunkr although it is running fine in local machine.

This is the index.html:

```
<div ng-app="MyServiceModule" ng-controller="MyController as MyCtrl" >
    <train-directive trains="MyCtrl.trainList" open-screen=MyCtrl.openTrainScreen(trainName)>
    </train-directive>
</div>
```

This is app.js:

```
angular.module('MyServiceModule',[]);
angular.module('MyServiceModule').controller('MyController',MyController);
function MyController()
{
    console.log('MyController');
    vm = this;

    vm.openTrainScreen = function(trainName)
    {
            alert("train type"+trainName);
    }

    vm.trainList = [
                         {"trainName":"Shatabdi","trainType":"AC"},
                         {"trainName":"Rajdhani","trainType":"SLEEPER"}
                   ];
}
```

This is directive.js:

```
angular.module('MyServiceModule').directive('trainDirective',trainDirective);
trainDirective.$inject = ['$document'];

function trainDirective($document)
{
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'dropdowndirective.tmplt.html',

        scope: {
            trains: '=',
            openScreen : '&'
        },

         link: function(scope,element){
            scope.isPopupVisible = false;

            $document.bind('click', function(event){


var isClickedElementChildOfPopup = element.find(event.target).length > 0;


                if (isClickedElementChildOfPopup)
                    {
                    if(scope.isPopupVisible===true)
                        {
                        scope.isPopupVisible = false;
                        scope.$apply();
                        }
                    else{
                        scope.isPopupVisible = true;
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                    }
                if (!isClickedElementChildOfPopup)
                {
                    scope.isPopupVisible = false;
                    scope.$apply();
                }

              });
        } 
    };
}
```

And this is the template for the directive:

```
<div class="aia__createQuoteBtn">TRAIN LIST</div>

<ul data-ng-repeat="train in trains" data-ng-show="isPopupVisible">
<li data-ng-click="openScreen({trainName:train.trainName})">{{ train.trainName }}</li>
</ul>
```

I am writing test cases for the directive.

I want to test the following points:

Case 1.The directive's scope variables are binded properly or not.

Case 2. I want to simulate the click function and check if the value of the variable   `isPopUpVisible` is toggling or not.

For Case 1, I wrote the following test case:

```
expect(element.isolateScope().openScreen).toBeDefined();
```

and this is passing for the function defined but is there a way I can test 2-way binding for `scope.trains`.

For Case 2, I wrote the following test case:

```
 it('Should respond to click', function(){
          scope.isPopupVisible = false;
          scope.isClickedElementChildOfPopup = true;
          element.triggerHandler('click');

          expect(scope.isPopupVisible).toBe(true);
        });
```

`scope` is defined in the following way:

```
scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
```

But this test case is failing saying "`Expected false to be true`"
I think I am not able to access the isPopupVisible variable of directive in the test case. I even tried with `element.isolateScope().isPopupVisible` but it is giving it as undefined.

Any help is appreciated.